# Dissolving polygons within another polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, overlapping-features, dissolve

I have multiple pixels in a shapefile *'delete_pixels.shp'* that are within a different polygon *'delete_id.shp'*.

I would like to dissolve the pixels that are within the polygons of *'delete_id.shp'*. However, the pixel values range from 60 to 320 so dissolving solely based on an attribute does not work in this case. It will still lead to multiple pixels being an alone entity within the bugger.

How can I do that?

Data is here, I have only included one example, but I have some thousands of these cases: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13MLu6Q1YDMRcrJJUdxhLW_XWowPb4JT_/view?usp=sharing

[image: figure]

Comment: [1] Select by location > [2] Dissolve

Comment: That is too simplistic. I have multiple cases like this, I only chose to show one in my data set. Dissolving these on an attribute results in multiple pixels not being dissolved since they have different values.